# JavaScript event listener firing when declared, and never again

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a unique little problem.  I have to show and hide a container, when a specific radio button is selected.  Unfortunately my event listeners are being fired when declared, and not when the event actually occurs.  Has anyone else run in to this sort of issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>

<body>
    <form name="form">
       <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1_yes" value="yes">
       <input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1_no" value="no">
       <div id="r1_comments" class="comments">Comments r1</div>
       <br />

       <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2_yes" value="yes">
       <input type="radio" name="r2" id="r2_no" value="no">
       <div id="r2_comments" class="comments">Comments r2</div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCommentTrigger(element, comments, trigger) {
    if (element.value===trigger && element.checked) { comments.style.display="block"; }
    else { comments.style.display="none"; }
}

function comments(fieldName, commentsID, triggerValue) {
    var t_elements, t_comments, i;

    t_elements = document.getElementsByName("fieldName");
    t_comments = document.getElementById(commentsID);

    t_comments.style.display="none";        


    for (i=0; i<t_elements.length; i++) {
        if (t_elements[i].addEventListener){t_elements[i].addEventListener("click",checkCommentTrigger(this, t_comments, triggerValue),true);}
        else {t_elements[i].addEvent('onclick',checkCommentTrigger(this,t_comments,triggerValue));}
    }
}

comments("r1","r1_comments","no");
comments("r2","r2_comments","no");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're **calling** the function in your "addEventListener" call.  That is, in this code (broken into two lines):

```
   if (t_elements[i].addEventListener){
      t_elements[i].addEventListener("click",checkCommentTrigger(this, t_comments, triggerValue),true);}
```

you're calling the "checkCommentTrigger()" function.  What you have to do is pass in a *reference* to a function, so something like this:

```
   if (t_elements[i].addEventListener){
      t_elements[i].addEventListener("click",function() { checkCommentTrigger(this, t_comments, triggerValue) },true);}
```

Same for the other branch of the "if":

```
   else {
      t_elements[i].attachEvent('onclick',function() { checkCommentTrigger(this,t_comments,triggerValue) });}
```

Also, you want "attachEvent()" for IE, not "addEvent()".

*edit* — looking at this again, there'll be a problem in that code if you use it as I wrote above. The problem will stem from the reference to `this` in the function to use as an event handler.  I think that you want the first argument to "checkCommentTrigger" to be the element to be checked.  It might be simplest to set up a *separate* function:

```
  function handlerFor(element, comments, value) {
    return function() {
      checkCommentTrigger(element, comments, value);
    }
  }
```

Then you can call that when you need an event handler function:

```
  if (t_elements[i].addEventListener){
      t_elements[i].addEventListener("click", handlerFor(t_elements[i], t_comments, triggerValue), true);
  }
```

Comment: Whoops, look at that, I also had fieldName as a string inside my getElementsByName...  Thank you Pointy, lifesaver.